# prayer is accepted or answered?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between the use of '**accepted**'  and '**answered**' when used with '**prayer**'? Supposing, we say:

> 1. His prayer was accepted.
> 2. His prayer was answered.

Are the two same? I think in the one with 'answered' we get the immediate result but when we say 'accepted' we hope Lord has accepted it but the result may come soon or later. Is this so?

Comment: I've never heard the expression *The Lord accepted your prayer.* I could analyze its individual words—but it sounds strange to me. (While people might know that a prayer has been *answered*, how could anybody know that a prayer has been *accepted*? Barring belief that all prayers are accepted, of course. But, in that case, saying so would be redundant.)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding prayers and the will of the Lord, there is no exact science. Therefore, we cannot have a guaranteed best, most correct answer to this question.

However, if we assume that the words word like in many other cases (when prayers and the Lord are not explicit in the sentence), then your understanding is (mostly) correct.

- answered: can mean either "Yes, wish granted. Go happy!", or it can mean "Nope, not this time. Please try again later."
- accepted: is actually more ambiguous. In the strict sense, it means "I heard you and you did not make me angry. Your request is now in the pile of requests on my desk." But it can have also an extended meaning, identical with "answered".